# How to use different Header for the different component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, gatsby

This is my main `app.js` file having all the routes. Now There are two `Header` components. Now I need to use  `Header1`
with only the `MyProfile` and `Home` components and `Header2` with `Marketing`. How can I do that with best approach?

```
const App = (props) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Layout>
      <Header1 {...props}/>
      <Header2 {...props}/>
      <Router>
        {/*<PrivateRoute path="/app/profile" component={Profile} />*/}   
        <Marketing path="/app" {...props}/>
        <PrivateRoute  path="/app/my-profile" component={MyProfile} location={props.location}/>
        <PrivateRoute  path="/app/home" component={Home} location={props.location}/>
      </Router>
    </Layout>
  </Provider>
)

export default App
```

Comment: so remove headers from `app` component and render it in the needed palce

Comment: I have to take `Header` as a parent not the child.

Comment: This is not exactly the definition of parent/child component. either conditionally render one of the headers according to the path or the props, or render one Header and apply related changes to view of it regarding the passed props

Comment: Pls post the solution. I will definitely think over it.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution for your problem could be, to explicitly define which components need to be rendered inside the Route. But I don't think that's the best approach you could take.

```
<Route path='/app/my-profile' render={ props =>
  <>
    <Header1 {...props} />
    <MyProfile />
  </>
} />
```

Another solution, I thought of could be to include the header inside the MyProfile component. In my opinion that's the more elegant way to do it.
So your App.js would only include Route paths and your components will take care of what they include:

```
const App = (props) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Layout>
      <Router> 
        <Marketing path="/app" {...props}/>
        <PrivateRoute  path="/app/my-profile" component={MyProfile} location={props.location}/>
        <PrivateRoute  path="/app/home" component={Home} location={props.location}/>
      </Router>
    </Layout>
  </Provider>
)

export default App
```

And your MyProfile components could look like this:

```
const MyProfile = (props) => (
  <>
      <Header1 {...props}/>
      <p>This is my profile</p>
  </>
)

export default MyProfile
```

Comment: ok suppose I have a dropdown in my header component and Now I need to pass the  value of the dropdown to the my profile page which I can do but now when i go to home page I need to maintain the same stage of that header dropdown how can i do that?